# How do remove all buttons in the UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an UITextView in my iPhone app which is editable.

New button is created inside the UITextView whenever user select a specific function.

I want to "clear" all buttons in the UITextView.

The code below is the way I add my button in the text view. How do I remove all the buttons in the text view?

Does anybody have any ideas or has anybody else achieved anything similar?

Thanks

```
....
....
....
for(int i = 0; i < array.count; i++)
{     
  object = [array objectAtIndex:i];          
  button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
  [button setTitle:object.name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  button.tag = object.ID;
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteTag:)
  [txtTagView addSubview:button];             
}
....
....
....
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (UIView *subview in [txtTagView subviews]){
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: This what I have been looking for! Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(id subview in [self subviews]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your buttons from their super view (in your case the super view is the textView for the buttons). `[yourButton removeFromSuperview];` So run that in a loop just like how you do while creating them.

Comment: I tried this before, but it only remove 2 buttons. Rest of the button still remain in the text view.

Comment: Then I'd suggest post THAT code where you try to remove buttons. That will help us debug.

Comment: Then you are simply not removing all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this for removing all buttons:

```
for (UIButton* tempButton in txtTagView) {
            [tempButton removeFromSuperView];
                        }
```

hope this will help you :)